# Excel 1004 error - Application or Object Defined

Tags: vba, excel

I tried googling an answer for why I'm getting this but nothing helps so far.  The sheet isn't protected. Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
Sub category_sums()

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
ws.Activate

Set MyRg1 = ws.Range("$A$2:$A$582")
Set MyRg2 = ws.Range("$H$2:$H$58")

ws.Range("J17").Formula = "=SumIf((MyRg1,""Auto/Transportation"", MyRg2)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ranges need to be same length, concatenate address from variables in and drop the additional bracket. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declare all your variables.

```
Option Explicit
Sub category_sums()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, MyRg1 As Range, MyRg2 As Range
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    ws.Activate

    Set MyRg1 = ws.Range("$A$2:$A$582")
    Set MyRg2 = ws.Range("$H$2:$H$582")

    ws.Range("J17").Formula = "=SumIf(" & MyRg1.Address & ",""Auto/Transportation"", " & MyRg2.Address & ")"

End Sub
```